# Setup FTP server in Openshift

Tags: cloud, openshift, opencart2.x

I install Opencart in Openshift cloud hosting so how to i setup ftp server in this 
I mean in opencart 2.x need ftp account to upload ocmod
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Openshift is no standard web hosting service. You are able to use SFTP that connect to the files on openshift over SSH, using your public keypair to authenticate.

From your post i got the impression that this would not work, because you probably use an external service that only supports FTP with a username/password authentication.